# Given a dense set $E$, what can we say about $\mathbb{R}$ \ $E$

Tags: real-analysis

My original thought regarding that question was that you would end up with a non dense set. However, if I think about $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ that leaves just the irrational numbers which I'm pretty sure is a dense set. So would the only time when you remove a dense set from $\mathbb{R}$ and get a set that isn't dense be $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{R}$? Since that is obviously the empty set.

Also, if it is true that when you remove a dense set from $\mathbb{R}$ other than $\mathbb{R}$ you get a dense set, how would I start a proof of that?

Comment: Remove all non-zero real numbers from $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Let $S$ be the set $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$. Then $S$ is dense but $\mathbb R \setminus S$ is not.

Comment: @PrimeMover Ok, so does that mean we can't say anything regarding the density of $E$ \ $\mathbb{R}$?  Since it could either be dense or not dense.

Comment: @Harames $E \setminus \mathbb{R}$ can be either dense nor dense. The only thing we can say about it is that it has an empty interior.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb R \setminus E$? If $E \subseteq \mathbb R$ then $E \setminus \mathbb R = \varnothing$.